# How to insert text & image content to google document by PHP code

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I'm using the lib of google API : composer require google/apiclient:^2.0 from : https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php

Anybody can help me how to create new google document file then insert text & image by API ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an available [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/images) for inserting image into document using  [`InsertInlineImageRequest`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate#InsertInlineImageRequest) method.

```
$requests = array();
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
    'insertInlineImage' => array(
        'uri' => 'https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/docs_64dp.png',
        'location' => array(
            'index' => 1,
        ),
        'objectSize' => array(
            'height' => array(
                'magnitude' => 50,
                'unit' => 'PT',
            ),
            'width' => array(
                'magnitude' => 50,
                'unit' => 'PT',
            ),
        )
    )
));

// Execute the requests.
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));
$response =
    $docsService->documents->batchUpdate(DOCUMENT_ID, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

The method inserts the image as a new `ParagraphElement` with an `InlineObjectElement` of length 1 where the `startIndex` is the request's location. You can also optionally specify a size to resize the image.

Comment: Thanks you very much, can you help me how to add new text ? seem insert text support java & python only ?